# Filtrar campos únicos utilizando Pandas Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

no arquivo 1.xlsx existem 2 colunas com datas, consegui verificar as ocorrências das datas nas colunas utilizando o 'isin' retornou 19 datas que não se repetem e agora preciso saber quais são essas datas para tratar, alguém tem ideia de como poderia fazer para o Python ler essas datas diferentes e imprimir? Grato desde já.

```
read = pd.read_excel("./1.xlsx")

df1 = read['Eventos']
df2 = read['Timestamp']

result = read['Eventos'].isin(read['Timestamp']).value_counts()


print(result)
```

[image: retorno]

Comment: Isso resolve? `result = read[read["Eventos"].isin(read["Timestamp"])]`

Comment: Infelizmente não, mas agradeço a resposta.

Comment: Coloque pelo menos um exemplo mínimo para que possa replicar o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que isso aqui vai funcionar:

```
result = read.loc[read.Eventos.isin(read.Timestamp) == False]
print(result.head())
```

Da próxima vez, põe um exemplo dos seus dados pra quem for te responder já te dar uma resposta testada.